# Finding the general solution using variation of parameters: $\left(1-x\right)y''+xy'-y=2\left(x-1\right)^2e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I need to find the general solution to the following ODE, given that the first solution is $y_1=e^x$ :
$\left(1-x\right)y''+xy'-y=2\left(x-1\right)^2e^{-x}$

I tried to solve the homogenous equation first, using $y_2\left(x\right)=u\left(x\right)y_1\left(x\right)=u\left(x\right)e^x$.

I got this solution: $u\left(x\right)=\left(C_2-C_1x\right)e^{1-x}\:\:\rightarrow \:\:y_2=u\left(x\right)y_1\left(x\right)=\left(C_2-C_1x\right)e^{-x}e^x=C_2-C_1x$

After that I tried to find the general solution:

$W=\begin{pmatrix}y_1&y_2\\ y_1'&y_2'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^x&x\\ e^x&1\end{pmatrix}=\left(1-x\right)e^x$

$v_1=-\int \frac{f\left(x\right)y_2\left(x\right)}{W},\:\:\:\:\:\:v_2=\int \frac{f\left(x\right)y_1\left(x\right)}{W}\:$

$v_1=-\int \frac{2\left(1-x\right)xe^{-x}}{\left(1-x\right)e^x}=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-2x}$

$v_2=\int \frac{2\left(1-x\right)e^{-x}e^x}{\left(1-x\right)e^x}=-e^{-x}$

$y\left(x\right)=v_1y_1+v_2y_2=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-2x}e^x-e^{-x}x=-\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$

However, a quick check has showed that this solution is wrong. I'd appreciate it a lot if someone could show me where I went wrong and explain how to solve this equation properly...

Comment: Are there any initial conditions?

Comment: First I'm asked to find the general soultion to the homogenous equation without any conditions, and then with the conditions: $y'\left(0\right)=0,\:\:y\left(0\right)=1$.  Then to find the solution to the non-homogenous equation without and with the same conditions...

Comment: Shouldn't the second integration be $$v_2 = -2 e^{-x}$$ The rest looks great.

Comment: If you take a derivative you get a linear equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y_p\left(x\right)=v_1y_1+v_2y_2=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-2x}e^x-\color{red}{2e^{-x}x}$$
$$y_p(x)=-xe^{-x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{2}$$
A factor two is missing in the integral of $v_2$.
$$v_2=\int \frac{2\left(1-x\right)e^{-x}e^x}{\left(1-x\right)e^x}=2\int e^{-x}dx=-2e^{-x}$$